# Resizing panels in a GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I want this:

[image]

My frame is a GridLayout (3,2), and all I can have is this:

[image]

I put the button in a panel, I think it's easier.  But how can I change the size of the grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose another `LayoutManager` e.g. `GridBagLayout`

Comment: If that wasn't what I wanted to say, I'd suggest it was a comment :P +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think that's answer but will post in comment next time:)

Comment: No. It's the answer and its fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen, GridLayout makes all of the cells in a grid the same size.

Your layout consists of two JPanels inside of a main JPanel.

The main JPanel will have a BoxLayout with a Y axis.

The panel JPanel will have a GridBagLayout.

The button JPanel will have a FlowLayout.